# Passing the data rejected by a promise to a function

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I've found this code, but I don't understand how can passing a function name into the `.catch(function name)` make that function take the data rejected by the promise as an argument and get invoked.

if it was something like `.catch(arg => {func(arg)})`, then I would not get confused..

```
let prom = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  reject("something");
})

prom.catch(func);



function func(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

Comment: Think of it like, catch is a function which takes a function as an argument. It just calls the function passed as argument  with whatever data it receives as rejected.

Comment: And `arg => {... }` is an anonymous function which is simply being replaced with `func` reference instead

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw 'Uh-oh!';
});

promise1.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
// expected output: Uh-oh!
```

[api doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)